# How to extract the part before the last '@' character of an email in postgresql?

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring

Example email: `ex@mpleEm@il@mymail.com`

Expected result: `ex@mpleEm@il`

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? You may do that in a lot of ways.

Comment: `ex@mpleEm@il@mymail.com` is an invalid email to begin with

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well my method is quite inefficient and not good for maintenance, so I'm looking for a simple code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`substring(string from pattern):`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

```
select substring('ex@mpleEm@il@mymail.com' from '(.*)@');

  substring   
--------------
 ex@mpleEm@il
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is probably to use [a POSIX regular expression match](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```
select substring('ex@mpleEm@il@mymail.com' from '(.*)@');
```

There are two slightly subtle things going on here:

- Under the rules of POSIX regexes, the `.*` matches *as much as possible*, which is why it includes the extra `@`s (compare `select substring('ex@mpleEm@il@mymail.com' from '(.*?)@');` which has a "non-greedy" modifier)
- The `substring` function returns the contents of the first capture if there are any capturing parentheses, which is why it *doesn't* include the final `@` (compare `select substring('ex@mpleEm@il@mymail.com' from '.*@');` which has no capturing parentheses)